# How do I find top 10 or top few CPU intensive threads created by Java process in Linux?

Tags: java, linux, performance, cpu-usage

How do I find top 10 or top few CPU intensive thread stack traces created by Java process in Linux ? I would like to know how much time spent as well if possible

Comment: You would have to use standard Linux tools to do this, Java has no notion of CPU use.  The thread id's can then be matched with a thread dump from Java to get the stack traces.

Comment: I hear there are some new tools although I am not sure

Answer (score 0):

This is simple and easy. And it worked! We need more tools like this in Java.

`https://github.com/patric-r/jvmtop`

You get the below information by using one command `jvmptop.sh <pid>`

[image]

Comment: its a open source project and might put a huge penalty of on your results, hence i will still recommend to cross check it yourkit profiler. you can try with 15 days of free evaluation of yourkit.

Comment: Naw, yourkit is so heavy weight and its not free and its not simple enough to just type something in command line and figure out what is going on. what you mean huge penalty? it is working great so far. Like I said these are the tools that makes life easy for developers IMO.

Comment: i am not against the open-source tools and infact i myself consume lots of open source tech and tools. Any profiling tool will put some penalty on the application , to report the stats. but enterprise versions will have more chances less penalty and accurate results. As i said you can use trial version of yourkit for free and just cross check the results.

Comment: I am against commercial tools. And I believe open source can build tools on par or even better than commercial products. Look how simple it is to use than setting up the heavy weight yourkit profiler. Many times we also have to debug remotely sometimes remote machines are not easily accessible since they have to go through a proxy or proxies in which case I don't even know how hard it is to set something up like yourkit profiler. Anyways jvmtop is simple and it gives what I want.

Answer (score -1):

Standard linux tool like `top` will just give top processes, which are consuming the most cpu. but will not be able to tell that what all the threads inside a single `java process` is taking most of the cpu.

You need a profiling tool like `YourKit` to determine what threads in java process is using most of the cpu and you can enable trace based sampling in `yourkit` to even get the `invocation count` of a method as well.

please refer https://www.yourkit.com/docs/java/help/cpu_intro.jsp doc , on how to get started with `CPU profiling` using yourkit.

Comment: Also Mission Control with Java Flight Recorder in Java 8 is pretty good. +1